# change the order of string in python

Tags: python

How do I change the sequence of string?
For e.g.

```
mys='4002-10-21'
```

Expected result:

```
'4002-21-10'
```

What I have tried:

I can enumerate the splitted string and then re-arrange the sequence like 1-3-2

```
newlist=list()
for i, v in enumerate(mys.split('-')):
    newlist.append(v)
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your approach?

Comment: are you trying to change dates from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-dd-mm`?

Comment: @VanPeer Yes. I am trying to change date but it is part of pandas string object. So looking for string function.

Comment: This question would've received a more appropriate answer had you given it the pandas tag. None of these answers are exactly fit for adaptation into  pandas code.

Comment: @shantanuo, I just discovered you wanted this to work in `pandas`. Please see my updated answer below, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) you can get multiple items with a single call:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> '-'.join(itemgetter(0,2,1)(mys.split('-')))
'4002-21-10'
```

With [string format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)  you can pick values from arguments:

```
>>> "{0}-{2}-{1}".format(*mys.split('-'))
'4002-21-10'
```

With [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) you can capture groups and reorder them (assuming digits):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)', r'\1-\3-\2', mys)
'4002-21-10'
```

If you need this in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) (as hinted in comments), you can use the regex-based approach in both [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace) and [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace), for example (add `inplace=True` for in-place subs):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['4002-10-21']})
>>> df.dates.replace(r'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)', r'\1-\3-\2', regex=True)
0    4002-21-10
Name: dates, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're really trying to just reformat datetime string, I suggest you parse the string to a datetime object and format it as you wish:

```
import datetime                                                                                   

def rearrange(*args):                                                                             
    return [datetime.datetime.strptime(arg, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%d-%m') for arg in args]
```

---

```
>>> rearrange('4002-10-21', '4002-10-28')
['4002-21-10', '4002-28-10']
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the context of the question, your approach is fine:

```
mys = '4002-10-21'
parts = mys.split('-')
mys = parts[0] + '-' + parts[2] + '-' + parts[1]
print(mys)  # "4002-21-10"
```

It's brittle certainly, but if it's for a personal or one-off script, who cares?  If you need more flexibility, then you'll need to describe more explicitly the nature of your constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
mys='4002-10-21'
```

You can simply write up a function for it such as this:

```
def change_order(string, split_char, *args):
    string = string.split(split_char)

    new_list = []

    for i in args:
        try:
            new_list.append(string[i])  # change to i-1 for abstracted parameters
        except IndexError:
            return False

    return split_char.join(new_list)
```

Which given `'4002-10-21'` with an `1, 3, 2` (actual code takes 1 away because it's zero-indexed) reordering gives:

```
>>> test.change_order('4002-10-21', '-', 0, 2, 1)
'4002-21-10'
```

Answer (score 3):

One good way is to use regular expressions this way the numbers which I presume can have different lengths eg: `'4002-21-1'` will also work fine.

```
    import re

    mys = '4002-21-10'

    parts = re.findall('[\d]+', mys) # finds all numbers that are next to each other
    print(parts) # just so you see what is created

    formatted_mys = parts[0] + "-" + parts[2] + "-" + parts[1] # put the parts together in the way you wanted
```

You can remove the `print` line if you wish of course. There are many others ways to do what you want but if you need it to be flexible this is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 2):

You can split on `-`, then re-join with `-` as the separator, but simply re-order as you need to:

```
>>> s = '4002-10-21'
>>> d = s.split('-')
>>> new_s = "-".join((d[0], d[2], d[1]))
'4002-21-10'
```

Or, without `join`, after you split, you can simply do:

```
new_s = "{}-{}-{}".format(d[0], d[2], d[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
mys='4002-10-21'
m = mys.split("-")
new_mys = m[0]+"-"+'-'.join(m[1:][::-1])
```

Output:

```
'4002-21-10'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
L='4002-10-21'
L=L.split("-")
L[i:3] = L[2:0:-1]
"-".join(L)
```

You could use slices.